# STL container assignment and const pointers

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, constants

This compiles:

```
int* p1;
const int* p2;
p2 = p1;
```

This does not:

```
vector<int*> v1;
vector<const int*> v2;
v2 = v1;  // Error!
v2 = static_cast<vector<const int*> >(v1);  // Error!
```

What are the type equivalence rules for nested const pointers?  I thought the conversion would be implicit.  Besides, I'd rather not implement point-wise assignment of STL containers, unless I really have to.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Direct assignment is not possible. As others explained, the equivalence is not established by the pointer types, but by the container types. In this case, vector doesn't want to accept another vector that has a different, but compatible element type.

No real problem, since you can use the `assign` member function:

```
v2.assign(v1.begin(), v1.end());
```

Comment: Why?  I would understand being hesitant about implicitly converting vector<char> to vector<int>, but int* to const int*?  I thought const receives special treatment in this regard.  Any idea why the C++ standard decided against it?

Comment: Perhaps something to do with templates are matched exactly, not always the most convenient.

Comment: I saw this example somewhere: an Apple is a Fruit, but a Bag of Apples is not a Bag of Fruit.  It would violate the Liskov Substitutability Principle: you can put an Orange into a Bag of Fruit, but you can't put an Orange into a Bag of Apples.  If Bag (or, in your case, vector<T>) were immutable, you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 20):

Conversion from `int*` to `const int*` is built into the language, but  vectors of these have no automatic conversion from one to the other.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is not the pointers, but the types of the two vectors. There are no standard conversions between templated types like those of v1 and v2 in your example.

This is perhaps easier to see in the following code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <char> cv;
    vector <int> iv;
    cv = iv;    // error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++ templated classes, each instantiation of the template is a completely different class - there is as much difference between `vector<int *>` and `vector<const int *>` as there is between `vector<int *>` and `vector<string>` or any other two classes for that matter.

It is possible that the committee could have added a conversion operator on `vector` to `vector<U>` as [Earwicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902667/stl-container-assignment-and-const-pointers/902707#902707) suggests - and you can go ahead and provide your own implementation of such a function:

```
template <class A, class T>
vector<T> convert_vector(const vector<A> &other)
{
    vector<T> newVector;
    newVector.assign(other.begin(), other.end());
    return newVector;
}
```

and use it like so:

```
vector<int*> v1;
vector<const int*> v2;
v2 = convert_vector<const int*>(v1);
```

Unfortunately, until C++0x comes with it's move constructors, this will be pretty bad performance-wise.

Answer (score 3):

It would be perfectly possible to write your own version of `vector` where this was possible. It would be identical to the standard type, but with a templated version of `operator=`, something like this:

```
template <class A>
vector2<T> &operator=(const vector2<A> &other)
{
    assign(other.begin(), other.end());
    return *this;
}
```

Where T is the element type of the whole class, whereas A is any type assignable to T.

It's not clear to me why `std::vector` doesn't have this.

Answer (score 2):

Dangerous, unless you know the types are absolutely compatible:

`v2 = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<const int *> & >(v1);`

Most STL implementations do use a specialization were all vectors of pointers share the same underlying implementation.  This is since (void *) is typically the same size as (int *) or any other pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

An important point not mentioned in any of the previous answers is that template specializations make this impossible to implement on a language-wide bases. Consider:

```
template<class T>
class Test
{
    T t;
};

template<>
class Test<const int>
{
    char array[1000];
};
```

Thus `Test<const int>` contains an array of chars, whereas `Test<int>` contains
a single int.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Test<int> t1;
    Test<const int> t2;
    cout << sizeof(t1) << endl; // gives 4
    cout << sizeof(t2) << endl; // gives 1000
    return 0;
}
```

In reality `vector<foo *>` and `vector<const foo *>` may hardly differ at
all --- in particular, they may have the same size. However, the possibility
of explicit template specialization means that they could differ
spectacularly, hence the reluctance of the compiler to allow conversion.

(This answer is mostly copied from http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/449611-cast-vector-foo-vector-const-foo#post1717570)

Answer (score 1):

[Coercion by Member Template](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Coercion_by_Member_Template) idiom is one possible approach to solve the problem. Essentially, a member template copy-assignment operator is added that allows the template class to participate in the same implicit type conversions (coercion) that are otherwise possible only on the type parameters of the class template. Although the idiom is used in the STL in other places, it is not available in std::vector.