# Can I cast std::vector<Animal*> to std::vector<Dog*> without looking at each element?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, casting

I have a base class with several classes extending it. I have some generic library utilities that creates a vector containing pointers to the base class so that any of the subclasses will work. How can I cast all of the elements of the vector to a specific child class?

```
// A method is called that assumes that a vector containing
// Dogs casted to Animal is passed.
void myDogCallback(vector<Animal*> &animals) {
    // I want to cast all of the elements of animals to
    // be dogs.
    vector<Dog*> dogs = castAsDogs(animals);
}
```

My naive solution would look something like this:

```
// A method is called that assumes that a vector containing
// Dogs casted to Animal is passed.
void myDogCallback(vector<Animal*> &animals) {
    // I want to cast all of the elements of animals to
    // be dogs.
    vector<Dog*> dogs;
    vector<Animal*>::iterator iter;
    for ( iter = animals.begin(); iter != animals.end(); ++iter ) {
        dogs.push_back(dynamic_cast<Dog*>(*iter));
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902667/stl-container-assignment-and-const-pointers

Comment: It isn't quite dupe - note that he's not copying from `vector<Derived*>` to `vector<Base*>`, but the other way around!

Comment: I guess he's looking for an automatic / implicit downcast!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. :) Wasn't sure how to ask this and yeah, had a hard time knowing what to search for!

Answer (score 12):

You could use `std::transform`. It still uses `for()` internally, but you'll get two-string implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Animal { virtual ~Animal() {} };
struct Dog : Animal { virtual ~Dog() {} };

template<typename Target>
struct Animal2Target { Target* operator ()( Animal* value ) const { return dynamic_cast<Target*>(value); } };

void myDogCallback(vector<Animal*> &animals) {
{
    vector<Dog*> dogs;
    transform( animals.begin(), animals.end(), dogs.begin(), Animal2Target<Dog>() );
}
```

Comment: This is still "looking at each element", the flow is just arranged differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written will put a bunch of null pointers into your dogs vector when the animals vector contains other animal specializations.

```
vector<Dog*> dogs;
vector<Animal*>::iterator iter;
Dog* dog;

for( iter = animals.begin(); iter != animals.end(); ++iter )
{
  dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(*iter);
  if( dog )
  {
    dogs.push_back( dog );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is not very good to use dynamic_cast for downcasting. You should probably refactor your code so that you do not need to use explicit downcasting.

See [CPP FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.4) for some more information.

**UPD** Also, see [Stroustrup page](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html) (search for "Why can't I assign a vector to a vector?")

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.  The simplest is to use something like `remove_copy_if`.  I cannot explain why they call it this, but it copies the elements from one container to another that **don't** satisfy the predicate.  Here's the basic idea (untested):

```
struct IsDog : unary_function < Animal *, bool > {
  bool operator ()(Animal * animal) const {
    return dynamic_cast <Dog*> (animal);
  }
};

void foo (vector<Animal*> animals) {
  vector<Dog*> dogs;
  std::remove_copy_if (animals.begin ()
    , animals.end ()
    , back_inserter (dogs)
    , std::not1 ( IsDog () ) );  // not1 here negates the result of IsDog!


  // dogs now contains only animals that were dogs
```

}

I suppose a way to look at `remove_copy_if` is to think of it as `copy_unless`.

An alternative approach, if you base your code around iterators only, is to wrap the iterator for vector < Animal* > with one that returns only the dogs from the collection.  The key advantage here is that you still only have one container, but of course you pay a bit more since you're algorithm will navigate over the entire collection of animals.

```
class dog_iterator  // derive from std::iterator probably with bidirectinoal tag
{
private:
  vector<Animals*>::iterator getNextDogIter (vector<Animals*>::iterator iter) {
    while (iter != m_end) {
      if (0 != dynamic_cast<Dog*> (*iter)) {
        break;
      }
      ++iter;
    }
    return iter;
  }

public:
  dog_iterator (vector<Animals*>::iterator iter, vector<Animals*>::iterator end)
  : m_end (end)
  , m_iter (getNextDogIter (iter))
  {
  }

  // ... all of the usual iterator functions

  dog_iterator & operator++ ()
  {
    // check if m_iter already is at end - otherwise:
    m_iter = getNextDogIter (m_iter + 1);
    return *this;
  }
  // ...
};
```

This is very rough, but I hope it shows you the basic principle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you can guarantee that each element is really a Dog then just `static_cast` i.e.

```
void myDogCallback(vector<Animal*> &animals) {

    const vector<Animal*>::size_type numAnimals = animals.size();

    vector<Dog*> dogs;
    dogs.reserve( numAnimals );

    for ( vector<Animal*>::size_type i = 0; i < numAnimals; ++i ) {
        dogs.push_back(static_cast<Dog*>( animals[i] ));
    }
}
```

I usually always get a knee-jerk reaction from people that this is bad and you should always use `dynamic_cast` but, in reality, if you can make guarantees about the type then it's perfectly safe and IMO a sensible thing to do.

Also, your guarantee would imply that the new vector has the same size so reserve the same space to avoid doing any allocations in each `push_back`. As an alternative loop I've used an index just because I always think iterating using an index must be quicker than an iterator but that's probably nonsense :)

Answer (score 0):

When you can assure, that your `std::vector<Animal*>` contains only `Dog*` you can use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: violates strict aliasing: https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8

Answer (score 0):

Mixing the `std::transform` methodology with a `static_cast` (because you are certain of its safety) could look like:

```
std::transform(animals.begin(), animals.end(),
               std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<Dog*>>(dogs),
               [](auto ptr) { return static_cast<Dog*>(ptr); });
```