# C-style cast of std::vector

Tags: c++, c, c++11, casting, static-cast

I stumbled upon this implementation in an existing code base when trying to find a solution to casting an `std::vector<Derived *>` to a `std::vector<Base *>`. I am using C++11.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
    // some implementation details
};

class B : public A
{
    // some implementation details
};

void count(std::vector<A *> const & a_vec)
{
  std::cout << "IT HAS THESE MANY PTRS: " << a_vec.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  B * b;

  std::vector<B *> b_vec {b};
  count((std::vector<A *> &) b_vec);

  return 0;
}
```

It felt extremely dodgy and so I tried to find an alternative. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902703/7168080) suggested an approach using `std::vector::assign`. So now, 
 my main function would look like this:

```
int main()
{
  B * b;

  std::vector<B *> b_vec {b};
  std::vector<A *> new_vec;
  new_vec.assign(b_vec.begin(), b_vec.end());
  count(new_vec);

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and works as expected. Now I have the following questions:

1) Why does the first snippet even compile but using a `static_cast` causes a compilation error?

2) What is the computational cost of the two methods? I expect the second one to incur into extra costs due to creating the temporary vector object `new_vec`, but I am not sure.

3) What are the drawbacks of using the C-style cast in these cases?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Just because something compiles doesn't mean that it'll work, or will produce the correct results. 2) Doing things the right way is usually more work than taking illegal shortcuts 3) The drawback is that it's undefined behavior.

Comment: A C-style cast tells the compiler "Just shut up and do it!". That "takes care of" the error or warning message, but then it is up to you whether it actually works. The compiler will not tell you, as you just asked it not to.

Comment: Runtime polymorphism and the STL do not mix well. This is an alternative, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the first snippet even compile but using a static_cast causes a compilation error?

Because a C-style cast is a sledgehammer that will throw all caution to the wind. Its motto is "you want it? you got it", regardless of what "it" is. A static cast will only do a cast that is correct in terms of static type checking.

> What is the computational cost of the two methods? I expect the second one to incur into extra costs due to creating the temporary vector object new_vec, but I am not sure.

Your expectation is correct. But the cost of code with well defined semantics can be in added work for the program.

> What are the drawbacks of using the C-style cast in these cases?

That it will always compile, and you won't find out there's a problem until you try to run it, on some platform in the future. Because it *may* work today.

Answer (score 2):

That code is nonsense. There is no requirement that the **value** of a `Derived*` is the same as the **value** of a `Base*`, so telling the compiler to pretend that a `std::vector<B*>` is a `std::vector<A*>` is not required to to anything sensible. In fact, that pointer type pun is impossible if you have multiple bases of the same type. Try it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int i;
};

struct I1 : Base {
    int j;
};

struct I2 : Base {
    int k;
};

struct Derived : I1, I2 {
    int l;
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base* b1 = &(I1&)d;
    Base* b2 = &(I2&)d;
    std::cout << (void*)&d << ' ' << (void*)b1 << ' ' << (void*)b2 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There are many cases in C++ where the specification allows the compiler to not give an error, but where the behaviour of the resulting program is undefined. C-style casts are largely a legacy compatibility leftover from the C heritage, and invokes undefined (often broken) behaviour in a lot of cases.
2. Theoretically the compiler can optimise it away, but most likely yes, it will incur some computational cost. It's likely smaller than e.g. the overhead of calling all of those objects, which you would presumably do after having cast them.
3. C-style cast have the drawback that it doesn't prevent you from invoking undefined behaviour, and doesn't make it clear what your intent is (e.g. with `auto x = (Foo) someConstType`, did you mean to remove a `const` qualifier or was that by accident?).

In your specific case, the C-style version will yield an incorrect program if you have multiple inheritance, and up-casting a pointer means its address needs to change to point to the appropriate base class object.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::vector<Derived*>` is a type unrelated to a `std::vector<Base*>`.  There is no legal way to interpret the memory of one as the other, short of something insanely stupid like placement new.

Your attempts generate errors if you are lucky.  If you are not, they generate undefined behavior, which means it may seem to work today but tomorrow they can silently format your hard drive due to anything from a compiler upgrade, to code far away being changed, or the phase of the moon.

Now, it is the case that many of the operations on a `vector<Base*>` work on a `vector<Derived*>`.  We can handle this with *type erasure*.

Here is a low-efficiency type erasure class:

```
template<class R, class...Args>
using vcfunc = std::function<R(void const*, Args...)>;

template<class T, class R, class...Args, class F>
vcfunc<R,Args...> vcimpl( F&& f ) {
  return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](void const* pt, Args&&...args)->R{
    return f( *static_cast<T const*>(pt), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  };
}
template<class T>
struct random_access_container_view {
  using self=random_access_container_view;
  struct vtable_t {
    vcfunc<std::size_t> size;
    vcfunc<bool> empty;
    vcfunc<T, std::size_t> get;
  };  
  vtable_t vtable;
  void const* ptr = 0;
  template<class C,
    class dC=std::decay_t<C>,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<dC, self>{}, int> =0
  >
  random_access_container_view( C&& c ):
    vtable{
      vcimpl<dC, std::size_t>( [](auto& c){ return c.size(); } ),
      vcimpl<dC, bool>( [](auto& c){ return c.empty(); } ),
      vcimpl<dC, T, std::size_t>( [](auto& c, std::size_t i){ return c[i]; } )
    },
    ptr( std::addressof(c) )
  {}

  std::size_t size() const { return vtable.size( ptr ); }
  bool empty() const { return vtable.empty( ptr ); }
  T operator[](std::size_t i) const { return vtable.get( ptr, i ); }
};
```

Now this is a bit toy as it doesn't support iteration.  (Iterators are about as complex as the container I wrote above).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26799224cce7624f).

```
struct A {
    char name='A';
};

struct B:A {
    B(){ name='B'; }
};

void print_them( random_access_container_view<A> container ) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i ) {
        std::cout << container[i].name << "\n";
    }
}
int main() {
    std::vector<B> bs(10);
    print_them( bs );
}
```

Languages that permit containers-of-child to be treated as lists-of-base basically do the above kind of thing automatically.  Either the containers themselves have the equivalent of a virtual function table, or when you treat a container as a view to base a virtual function table is synthesized and used by the client code.

The above isn't maximally efficient; note that every `std::function` was stateless.  I could replace them with function pointers pretty easily, and store a static vtable based on the type `C` instead to save memory (but add an other indirection).

We can also do this a bit simpler with a non-view type, in that we could use the type erasure model-concept pattern instead of this manual vtable pattern.